# http post request not working in angularjs while http get works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api

I made a Web api and published it to localhost.

A web page was created where the script file was made using AngularJS.

Both api and webpage runs in localhost.

When I send an http get request I get a JSON response but cannot add data to api using Post method.

The post request works in Postman perfectly. It adds new data.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$scope.register = function () {

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/pool/api/employees/',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data:JSON.stringify({"PSID": "1236","Name": "Michael","Type": "Owner","Ph": "9585456211"})
    });
}

$scope.search = function () {
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/pool/api/employees/' + $scope.getid;
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.msg = "";
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.id = data.PSID;
        $scope.name = data.Name;
        $scope.type = data.Type;
        $scope.phone = data.Ph;
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        $scope.msg = "No PSID found";
        $scope.id = "";
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.type = "";
        $scope.phone = "";

    })
}
});
```

Web Api Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using webapi.Models;

namespace webapi.Controllers
{
        public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
        private webapiContext db = new webapiContext();

        // GET: api/Employees
        public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return db.Employees;
        }

        // GET: api/Employees/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployee(string id)
        {
            Employee employee = await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(employee);
        }

        // PUT: api/Employees/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutEmployee(string id, Employee employee)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != employee.PSID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/Employees
        [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Employees.Add(employee);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (EmployeeExists(employee.PSID))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.PSID }, employee);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Employees/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteEmployee(string id)
        {
            Employee employee = await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Employees.Remove(employee);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(employee);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool EmployeeExists(string id)
        {
            return db.Employees.Count(e => e.PSID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console?  without any errors or code showing what you are trying to do, it's impossible to know what might be wrong.

Comment: the same thing happened with me yesterday it was working fine with postman but not from API, please post some of your code to take a look at.

Comment: what console errors are you getting?